# VC++ move borderless form

Tags: winforms, visual-c++-2008

i'm totally new to C++, but anyway, how to move a borderless form (`this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::None;`)?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean as a user with the mouse or programmatically from either the program itself or a third party program?

Comment: @Mat user with the mouse

Answer (score 2):

That did it in MFC.  It enabled the window to move by dragging it by any point inside the window!

```
void MyWnd::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{
    PostMessage( WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, MAKELPARAM( point.x, point.y));
}
```